# How to get only the base model instances from query?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hopefully my question won't have been asked before.

I've the following models in my Django app:

```py
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    some_attribute = models.SomeField()

    def some_method(self):
        do_stuff()
    
    # Note: not abstract

class B(A):
    def some_other_method(self):
        do_other_stuff()
```

Now, if I have one `A` and one `B` in the database,
when I issue a `A.objects.filter()` call, I get the `A`
*and also the `B` instance* (as expected).

But what if I in fact only want the instances of `A` specifically?
I don't see how to write is as an `.exclude()` instruction.
Could filtering with `type == "A"` be the intended way?

Follow-up: what if I have a class `C` inheriting from `B`, and so on, and want to exclude all instances of inheriting models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
A.objects.filter(b=None)
```

to retrieve the `A` objects for which there is no `B` instance. This will make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the `B` model, and thus only retain items where `B` is `NULL`.

Or you can omit all subclasses of `A` with:

```
data = {
    f.name: None
    for f in A._meta.get_fields()
    if f.one_to_one and A in f.related_model.__mro__
}
A.objects.filter(**data)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and accurate response. I have a follow-up question -- editing now.

Comment: @augustebaum: If  `C` inherits from `B`, then `b=None` is sufficient.

Comment: Correct, I had missed that! Thanks again.